# Selenium -- How to handle situation when driver's current url is not updated quickly when navigating through a web application

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am using the PageObject model to develop a test framework, and I have one instance where it takes some time before a new page's url is available.

The scenario is this: The user is creating a new object. They provide the name of the object and click a button to go to the edit page for the new object.

I want to construct an EditPage object using the url which loads when the button is clicked. It takes some time before the driver's current url is updated to the new url for the edit page after the button is clicked.

In Selenium 2 what is a clean, robust way to handle this situation? So far, I have only encountered issues with specific elements not loading on a page, but this is the first time I have encountered a situation in which there is a long wait for the driver's current url to get updated.

I have used FluentWait for components which are slow to load and I have heard about WebDriverWait. My question is, which one is better to use for this situation? Can someone post a simple example of how to deal with a URL which is slow to be available? I want a solution that doesn't require the CreatePage to know anything about elements on the EditPage, so strategies that involve waiting for elements on the EditPage to be visible violate encapsulation principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem given that pages will wait a variable amount of time to load and your page objects need to take that into account. Page objects should have a mechanism built in to wait for themselves to load within your preferred allotted time so that if you do throw an exception you know it's either because 1) The page requested did not in fact show up or 2) It took too long. You can throw a different exception in each case to differentiate between the reasons why a test fails.

In your case I think the best thing to do is to have your page objects wait for a certain amount of time for the URL to match the URL of the page object in question. So as apart of their loading process the page object could call a methodlike the following:

```
public PageObject WaitForURL(string url)
{
    Console.WriteLine("WaitForURL : " + url);
    WebDriverWait _waitForURL = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000));
    _waitForURL.Until((d) =>
    {
        try
        {
            return d.Url == url;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
    Console.WriteLine("URL changed to : " + _driver.Url);

    return this;
}
```

Please note that even after the URL has changed to your desired URL it doesn't mean that the page has finished loading. You say you don't want to wait for a specific element and I understand that but you may want to do a simple wait after the above for the body tag to be visible or make sure that before you interact with the page object's elements the first time you start first by waiting for the element to be visible.

Comment: I have mechanisms on the page object class to verify that the specific elements are loaded. I like your solution for verifying that the URL has been updated. Once I have a new URL, I can create the page object and use the scaffolding of SlowLoadableComponent to verify that specific elements are loaded.

Comment: Awesome, sounds like you are well on your way. Good luck!